# CSS - Changing position from fixed to allow scrolling

Tags: html, css, scale

I am currently using some code to display an image in a 'scale to fill' type of way. The code I am using was used on a project I did a while ago to crate a background image for a site and now I want to change the positioning from fixed to allow scrolling. However I can't work out the margins and sizing.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="Main Page">

<div id="Background">
<img src="http://googledrive.com/host/0By-qb7dZ_m5feE94MkcwSWxLckU" />
<style>
#Background{
position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#Background img{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
</style>
</div>
```

Comment: what goes wrong when you change `fixed` to `absolute`?

Comment: @ToniLeigh The divs which are presented below it, don't display properly...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the background-image for the entire site, you can use this css-code:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://googledrive.com/host/0By-qb7dZ_m5feE94MkcwSWxLckU"); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Depending on your background-image you can try `background-size: cover;` instead of `background-size: 100% 100%;` for a better result too.

Here is a fiddle-example: https://jsfiddle.net/hxefwhpL/